# Issue with .Net Remoting

Tags: c#, multithreading, collections, .net-remoting

I am making an application in c#.I am using .Net Remoting for calling the method of windows application in web application.For communication between windows and web application i made one remoting object in which i declare one method.In windows application i have collection of one class and that class is declared in remote object.

Now my problem is that whenever i am calling the interface method,the collection value becomes zero.Before calling that method it contains some data.

Also whenever i am inserting hard coded value then its working but whenever i am inserting runtime value,its giving problem.I am using threading to insert the data into the collection.
Remote object has two components as StreamDataInfo.cs and IRemoteStreamData.cs as.These two are different classes in one class library.

```
namespace StreamDataService
{
     public interface IRemoteStreamData
    {
         List<string> GetPatientHistory(string BedID);
    }
}


namespace StreamDataService
{
 [Serializable] public class StreamDataInfo:MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public string m_PortNumber { get; set; }
        public string m_BedID { get; set; }
        public List<string> m_StreamData { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And in server application i wrote interface method as

```
 public List<string> GetPatientHistory(string PortNumber)
        {          
            StreamDataInfo objStreamDataInfo = new StreamDataInfo();
            lock (this)
            {
                objStreamDataInfo = (from temp in listStreamDataInfo
                                     where temp.m_PortNumber.Equals(PortNumber.ToString())
                                     select temp).SingleOrDefault();
            }
            return objStreamDataInfo.m_StreamData;
        }
```

Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question..? have you thought of creating this as a webService..? if not do you have an example of what you have thus far in regards to Code base..? runtime values vs hard coded sounds like an Instantiation or initialize issue with values going out of scope. are you declaring variables as private..? if so try protected that way if you are using methods from one base class in another you an access / assign those member variables.. need to really see what your code looks like to determine

Comment: my requirement is to use .net remoting.i know web service but i have to use remoting

Comment: ok .net remoting.. will also requite some pInvoking as well but lets have a look at some of your code.. perhaps a few additional eyes out here could help..?

Comment: Can you post some of the code where you are getting this issue (the section where your collection is staying empty, the code where you are filling the collection)

Comment: i used the all member variables public then also it does not working. In other methods it showing data.Only problem is with Interface method.

Comment: Can you post some code please? How is the class type defined? Is it Serializable?

Answer (score 0):

Generic collections are not supported in remoting. You can either use arrays or try your own implementation (a VB sample is [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/mcastro/archive/2006/01/23/66787.aspx)).